# Android DialogFragment animation can top to bottom?

Tags: android, animation

I have a DialogFragment,and want to with animation.
I want to move it top to bottom.

I try this xml,but I don't want to use scale,I want to use translate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

Comment: Your welcome. let me know if you need anything else.